# Dialog with checkbox in Android

Tags: android

I found example for dialog with checkbox:

```
final int DIALOG_ITEMS = 1;
    String data[] = { "one", "two", "three", "four" };
    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            Button but1=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
            but1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) 
                {
                     showDialog(DIALOG_ITEMS);
                }
            }); 
        }

        protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
            AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

              adb.setTitle(R.string.items);
              adb.setSingleChoiceItems(data, -1, myClickListener);


          }


          OnClickListener myClickListener = new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
              ListView lv = ((AlertDialog) dialog).getListView();
              if (which == Dialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE)
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "pos = " + lv.getCheckedItemPosition());
              else
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "which = " + which);
            }
          };
```

Eclipse atention about two errors:

> 1)
>   setSingleChoiceItems(int, int, DialogInterface.OnClickListener) in the
>   type AlertDialog.Builder is not applicable for the arguments
>   (String[], int,
>   View.OnClickListener) MainActivity.java   /master/src/com/example/hotdog_master   line
>   98    Java Problem
>
> 2)
>   View.OnClickListener(){} must implement the inherited abstract method
>   View.OnClickListener.onClick(View)    MainActivity.java   /master/src/com/example/hotdog_master   line
>   104   Java Problem

Could you help understend what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your OnClickListener as:

```
  DialogInterface.OnClickListener myClickListener = new 
                                   DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
              ListView lv = ((AlertDialog) dialog).getListView();
              if (which == Dialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE)
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "pos = " + lv.getCheckedItemPosition());
              else
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "which = " + which);
            }
          };
```

and Create `AlertDialog.Builder`  instance as:

```
AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(Your_Current_Activity.this);
```

**EDIT :**

Change your `onCreateDialog` method as:

```
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);

      adb.setTitle(R.string.items);
      adb.setSingleChoiceItems(data, -1, myClickListener);

       AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
       dialog.show();
      return super.onCreateDialog(id);  //<<<< add return here

  }
```

Comment: Then I have eror, 
This method must return a result of type Dialog MainActivity.java line 94 Java Problem

protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
  AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
       adb.setTitle(R.string.items);
       adb.setSingleChoiceItems(data, -1, myClickListener);
   }

Comment: :Then I heve error:
The return type is incompatible with Activity.onCreateDialog(int) MainActivity.java /master/src/com/example/hotdog_master line 94 Java Problem

Comment: @user1884872 : just put `  AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
       dialog.show();` before return . currently you are not able to see dialog because you are not create calling Create() and show() method for Dialog

Answer (score 1):

Change your above code as below:

```
DialogInterface.OnClickListener myClickListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
              ListView lv = ((AlertDialog) dialog).getListView();
              if (which == Dialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE)
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "pos = " + lv.getCheckedItemPosition());
              else
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "which = " + which);
            }
          };
```

You already imported View.OnClickListener for Button Click and eclipse is detecting the below onClickListener also as View.onClickListener(). So maintain differentiation by adding DialogInterface.OnClickListener